# Which .net reporting component use to have compatibility with Mono?

Tags: .net, mono, reporting

i have to develop a business (database driven) application in .NET (Winforms) with the  possibility to run it on Linux (using Mono ). 
I know Crystal Report is not "compatible" in Mono. So, my question is: which .Net component using for Printing report compatible in Mono and Linux / Mac Osx ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look at [monoreports](https://github.com/tomaszkubacki/monoreports).